# DOMDocument parse - How get style background-color from TD?

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

```
$contents = '<table><tr><td style="background-color:#fffddd;">Row 1 Column 1</td><td style="background-color:#444;">Row 1 Column 2</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:#555;">Row 2 Column 1</td><td style="background-color:#666;">Row 2 Column 2</td></tr></table>';

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($contents);

$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$str = "";
foreach ($items as $node) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $element) {
        $str .= $element->nodeValue . ", ";
    }
    $str .= "<br />";
}
echo $str;
```

It code return text in `td`, but how get style `background-color` from `td`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested it, but it should be:

```
$element->getAttribute('style');
```

If there are multiple styles in your style tag you can use a regex.

Update:

```
$re = "/background-color:\\s*(\\#.*?);/"; 
$str = "background-color: #fffddd; color: #000; font-size: 14px;"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` should contain the background color. But this is also not well tested. Could be that you have to tweak the RegEx a little bit for corner cases

Comment: oh thanks, i use ->style and get empty result (. but how get value `background-color`. with this code? i get full row `background-color:#fffddd;`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `style=""` attribute via `->getAttribute("style")`. In your `foreach`, you can add this:

```
$str = array();
foreach ($items as $node) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $element) {
        $str[] = array($element->nodeValue . ", ", $element->getAttribute("style"));
    }
}
```

Code above will return an 2-dimensional array, which contains value and style:

```
echo $str[0][0]; // Row 1 Column 1,
echo $str[0][1]; // background-color:#fffddd;
```

But, if your style will looks like (for example):

```
style="background-color: #fffddd; color: #000; font-size: 14px;"
```

the PHP return will be:

```
background-color: #fffddd; color: #000; font-size: 14px;
```

So if you need **ONLY** background-color, you will need parse this `style=""` return.